# Mojave TimeMachine add source path

Tags: time-machine, mojave

I am looking for a solution to add a path to include into the default backup rules for TM. To clarify, I dont search a solution to use a NAS drive as backup destination (as often is asked and alwyas is to find).

what about the idea, in my home I add a symlink (ln -s) to this folders?

thx a lot, Roland

Comment: To be clear you want to use your NAS, or part of it, as a TimeMachine server (a place to store your TimeMachine backups)? If that is correct the NAS vendor usually provides a way to configure the NAS as a TimeMachine server. That is how it works on my QNAP NAS. Once that is set up all you need do is set up TimeMachine on your Mac and choose your NAS as the target.

Comment: Steve, thanks for the comment. But I do not want to use NAS as a TM server. I want to add the data stored on NAS drive included into TM backup, wich is stored locally on a USB HDD. The NAS shall be the data source for my TM backup.